# QML Textinput inputmask with multiple mask guards

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to make TextInput inputMask guard multiple conditions? For example:

`inputMask: ("9999" || "9999-9999") // syntax probably wrong`

Accepted inputs:

- 1234
- 1234-3456

Edit: the right hand side input (xxxx-rhs) would also have to be greater than the left hand side.

Comment: You could use a [validator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-regexpvalidator.html) for allowing multiple varying inputs. The comparison of the LHS and RHS though isn't doable with regexp I suppose. You probably need to write a custom [QValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html) to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The validate implementation is probably not the most efficient or readable, but it does the job. Have a look at this GitHub repository [custom validator](https://github.com/iam-peter/customvalidator).

```
QValidator::State SpecialValidator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
{
    if (input.isEmpty())
        return QValidator::Acceptable;

    static QRegularExpression expression("^\\d{0,4}$");
    QRegularExpressionMatch expressionMatch = expression.match(input);

    if (expressionMatch.hasMatch()) {
        if (expressionMatch.captured(0).size() != 4)
            return QValidator::Intermediate;

        return QValidator::Acceptable;
    }

    static QRegularExpression advancedExpression("^(\\d{4})-(\\d{0,4})$");
    QRegularExpressionMatch advancedExpressionMatch = advancedExpression.match(input);

    if (advancedExpressionMatch.hasMatch()) {
        QString lhs = advancedExpressionMatch.captured(1);
        const QString rhs = advancedExpressionMatch.captured(2);

        if (rhs.isEmpty())
            return QValidator::Intermediate;

        if (rhs.size() == 4)
            return lhs.toInt() < rhs.toInt() ? QValidator::Acceptable : QValidator::Invalid;

        lhs.truncate(rhs.size());

        return lhs.toInt() <= rhs.toInt() ? QValidator::Intermediate : QValidator::Invalid;
    }

    return QValidator::Invalid;
}
```